# Whitespace in an identifier used from an handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

It is possible to have whitespace in an `Ember.Object`'s field name, but how to render its value?

The following JSFiddle illustrates my aim: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/aTpz4/

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible, since for Handlebars it looks like you want to use a helper named `my`.

Also in your example an error `Uncaught Error:  Handlebars error: Could not find property 'my' on object <.MyView:ember147>` is thrown.

You could write your own Handlebars helper, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/KAsNN/

**Handlebars**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-template">
    This does work: {{echo "myField"}}
    This does work: {{echo "my field"}}
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:​

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('echo', function(propertyName, options) {
    return Ember.getPath(options.contexts[0], propertyName);
});
```

The helper above is not bindings aware. There is a Pull Request for this: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/615

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea! This will provide a way out of my problem.